# «Наши – вперёд!» Или с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, обращение

«Наши – вперёд!» — это заголовок к статье.
«Наши» — это обращение, поэтому с запятой? Или же с тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой знак поставить? Это зависит от контекста.

Вот всем известное стихотворение Александра Межирова ["Коммунисты, вперед!"](https://rupoem.ru/mezhirov/est-v-voennom.aspx).

```
   Повсеместно,  
   Где скрещены трассы свинца,  
   Где труда бескорыстного — невпроворот,  
   Сквозь века,   
           на века,  
                 навсегда,  
                         до конца:  
   — Коммунисты, вперед! Коммунисты, вперед!
```

Здесь слово "коммунисты" является обращением, поэтому ставится запятая.

А вот другой отрывок, с другой пунктуацией ([Г. Бакланов. Пядь земли](https://thelib.ru/books/baklanov_grigoriy/pyad_zemli-read-10.html) (гл. XII)).

> — Как только начнется артподготовка, командирам рот, командирам взводов
> поднять бойцов! **Коммунисты — вперед!** Вперед, не останавливаясь! Не лежать
> под огнем! Когда сзади смерть, люди на пулеметы полезут.

Здесь не обращение, а констатация факта, что коммунисты идут впереди, приказ: *коммунисты* [идут] *— вперед* (сказуемое пропущено, ставится тире).

**Наши — вперёд!** В названии статьи, или движения, или плаката я бы выбрала вариант с тире: четко, коротко, эффектно.